# What are my options for accommodation whilst travelling by bicycle

Tags: camping, bicycles

I am travelling by bike, taking a tent, but what other options are available? For example, camping in Siberia in winter = bad or is it? Camping in the wild in parts of Kenya = bad therefore where to stay?

Comment: Like your other questions, we'll need more detail.  Where are you going? What season?  For example, camping in Siberia in winter = bad.  Camping in the wild in parts of Kenya = bad.  Please add more information about when and where you are going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main alternative would be to stay in hostels, bed&breakfast accomodations or hotels. It's much more comfortable, but also more expensive and requires some planning, at least if you're going through sparsely populated areas.

Some countries (especially in Europe) have designated long-distance bike trails, and along them you'll typically find so many accomodations that you can be quite spontaneous about where exactly you stop for the night.

Answer (score 1):

Having a bike and a tent, ring at some house, explain that you're traveling by bicycle and ask if you can put your tent in their garden.
It's possible that they invite you to sleep over at their house, propose a dinner and/or use their shower.

There are also hospitality networks, like
[warmshowers.org](http://warmshowers.org) dedicated to cyclists
[couchsurfing.org](http://couchsurfing.org)
[bewelcome.org](http://bewelcome.org)